# Check if library is loaded or initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using RS Slider JS library but I load it on a few pages not all the site then I have a script, which is common to all the site, where I trigger the libraries, for example:

```
var revapi;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

       revapi = jQuery('.tp-banner').revolution(
        {
            delay:9000,
            startwidth:1170,
            startheight:500,
            hideThumbs:10,
            lazyLoad:"on"

        });

});
```

In some cases, when library JS aren't loaded because I don't need it then this part of the code triggers some "minors" errors, so how do I check if JS was loaded or if `revolution()` object exists or something else to avoid that problem? What do yours handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that a specific class exists before initializing your plugin. If it doesn't the plugin function never gets called and won't throw errors

```
if( $('.revolutionClass').length ){
   /* initialize plugin */

}
```

Comment: Or simply `if ( $('.revolutionClass')[0] )`

Answer (score 1):

So you're asking how to determine if an object returned by `jQuery()` has that `revolution` function?

Why not do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var banner = jQuery('.tp-banner'),
        revapi;

    if (banner.revolution) {
        revapi = banner.revolution({
            delay:9000,
            startwidth:1170,
            startheight:500,
            hideThumbs:10,
            lazyLoad:"on"
        });
        // do other stuff with revapi
    }
});
```

Comment: `if ( jQuery(selector))` will always return truthy regardless if selector is valid since it still creates an object

Comment: @charlietfl, good point, that can come out. The thing I'd worry about with your solution is an element with that css class could be there without the plugin being loaded, no?